# Recibir email con informacion de un formulario PHP

Tags: php, formularios

un placer saludar. Tengo una consulta referente a un pequeño problema que tengo. Explico brevemente mi situacion.

Tengo un formulario del cual quiero recibir la informacion que ingrese el cliente en mi correo electrónico y poderle responder luego la consulta. En una oportunidad lo pude hacer con un ejercicio que hice y me funcionó perfectamente. En este caso estoy reciclando el código y cambiando la información propia de cada sitio. No me señala errores de ningún tipo me arroja el mensaje de envio exitoso pero no llega la informacion a mi correo.

Anexo el código

```
<form action="info-form.php" method="POST" id="contacto" class="contenedor centrar-texto">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input class="campo" type="text" name="name" placeholder="&nbsp;Ingrese su nombre" required>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="campo" type="email" name="email" placeholder="&nbsp;Ingrese su email" required>
        <label for="pais">País:</label>
        <select class="campo" name="country" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled>--Seleccione--</option>
          <option value="AF">Afganistán</option>
          <option value="AL">Albania</option>
          <option value="DE">Alemania</option>
        </select>
        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje" required></textarea>
      </fieldset>

      <?php
      if(isset($_GET['e'])) { 
        echo "<div>
                <h4>Tu mensaje fue enviado correctamente</h4>
              </div>" ;
      }
      ?>

      <input class="boton" type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

El cliente ingresa su información y esta a traves de mi archivo info-form.php debe enviarse a mi correo electronico para luego ser respondida la consulta y guardarse en una base de datos.

Anexo el código de mi archivo info-form.php

```
<?php 

$name_form=$_POST['name'];
$email_form=$_POST['email'];
$country_form=$_POST['country'];
$message_form=$_POST['message'];

$email_body="Name: ".$name_form."\r\n"."Email: ".$email_form."\r\n"."Country: ".$country_form."\r\n"."Message: ".$message_form;

$response="From: $name_form <$email_form>";

mail("micorreo@gmail.com", "Consulta desde luishernandez93.000webhostapp.com", $email_body, $response);

$connection_data=mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuarioBD", "claveBD", "nombreBD") or die ("Error al conectar con la base de datos");


mysqli_query($connection_data, "INSERT INTO consultas VALUES (DEFAULT, '$name_form', '$email_form', '$country_form', '$message_form')");

header("Location: contacto.php?e=ok#contacto");




 ?>
```

Cualquier opinion referente a mi situacion es muy bien recibida. He leído que puede ser tambien porque el sevidor no me permite esos envios en mi codigo por ser un usuario gratuito pero no se que tan cierto sea. No estoy muy empapado con el tema.

Comment: prueba quitando el header del final, si ocurre un error no te dejara verlo.

Comment: ¿Qué hay del **control de errores**? Hay al menos 6 posibilidades de errores en este contexto, y ninguna es controlada: 1. El POST podría estar llegando vacío; 2. El email puede no ser válido; 3. La función `mail()` puede fallar; 4. Puede no haber conexión; 5. La consulta SQL puede tener un error de sintaxis; 6. La consulta SQL puede fallar (por clave duplicada por ejemplo) ... Un programa que no controla los errores se convierte él en un programa erróneo en sí mismo. Si controlas lo antes dicho sabrás si el programa falla realmente y por qué falla. Si no falla, el mensaje estará en spam.